# How can I determine if Windows applies ASLR without rebooting?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-7, aslr, address-space

As far as I understand, [ASLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430720.aspx) <sup>Address Space Layout Randomization</sup> will only do random relocation per system start (per reboot).

> ### Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR)
>
> ASLR moves executable images into random locations when a system
>   boots, making it harder for exploit
>   code to operate predictably. (...)

If this is the case, how can I then "test" or, rather, check that ASLR is happening for my C++ module *or for a system module* (say, `kernel32.dll`) without repeatedly restarting Windows and hoping the randomness kicks in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would try:

Remember that a module's `HMODULE` handle is actually the base address of the module's image. You can use [`GetModuleHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to obtain this value. If you compare that to the base address in the image's optional header values, we would expect those two values to be different when ASLR is turned on.

Keep in mind that this would only be a clear indicator of ASLR when `GetModuleHandle` is used on certain system DLLs; it would work for `kernel32` because it is not a typical candidate for image relocation:

1. Microsoft system DLLs are all given unique recommended base addresses; and
2. It is one of the first DLLs mapped into the process address space.

Since `kernel32` wouldn't typically be relocated, if ASLR was turned off it would be reasonable to expect it to be loaded at its recommended base address.

How do you obtain the recommended base address from the image headers? The easiest way is to use the `DUMPBIN` utility included with Visual C++. If you'd rather do it programatically, you will need to do some spelunking through the executable image's headers until you locate the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` structure's `ImageBase` field. For more information about PE headers, I'd recommend ["An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) by Matt Pietrek.